# Use-case of the ServiceClient?

Tags: azure-iot-hub

Is the use-case of the ServiceClient to [send messages to devices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42411433/2103764)?

ServiceClient supports only amqp messages. Documentation for Azure Devices namespace says "Transport types supported by ServiceClient - Amqp and Amqp over WebSocket only". In code the TransportType exposes only Amqp. Would it be changed in the future?

If the ServiceClient is been used for C2D messages, why in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45704330/2103764), is written that "For ServiceClient, you need Azure IoT Hub connection string, not device connection string"?

What is the performance's impact and resources' utilization, if we hold a reference of the created ServiceClient object (or the Registry Manager)?

and what is the impact in case

1. when we open-close the connection?
2. when we leave open the conection?

Comment: To answer some of your questions:
The use cases for ServiceClient include sending C2D messages, managing the identity registry, invoking direct methods, and setting desired properties.
You need the IoT Hub connection string because the ServiceClient is connecting to an IoT Hub instance. A device connection string is used by a device to connect to IoT Hub - the device connection string enables a device to authenticate with IoT Hub.

Comment: @Dominic Betts, thanks, ServiceClient sends amqp messages to EventhHub queues (ServiceBus), as I understand.  1. Is it  safe to initialize it as a singleton when a actor process is started and to be used everywhere? 2. Is the RegistryManager more performant way to set server side properites, etc? 3. Does there exist a raw sample (without clients) for C2D, D2C, and server side properties, using only amqp messages +eventHub? thx again

Comment: @Dominic Betts, I can't find also in GitHub a sample to listen for twin notifications (twinChanged events)

Comment: You may find this sample useful for twinChange events: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/iot-hub-notifications-sync-graphdb/
I'm not aware of any raw samples that don't use the client SDKs.

Comment: @Dominic Betts, thank, I'll read it, probably it is useful. I 'd read another nice article of this guy I think.,

Comment: Just to make sure: for C2D messages the ServiceClient does NOT send messages to EventHub queues, it sends messages over AMQP to Iothub which sends the messages to devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the use-case of the ServiceClient to send messages to devices?

Yes. You need use ServiceClient to send C2D messages.

> ServiceClient supports only amqp messages. Documentation for Azure
>   Devices namespace says "Transport types supported by ServiceClient -
>   Amqp and Amqp over WebSocket only". In code the TransportType exposes
>   only Amqp. Would it be changed in the future?

For future plans, you can reference [this guide](https://github.com/azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp#contribution-feedback-and-issues) ask a question.

> If the ServiceClient is been used for C2D messages, why in this
>   answer, is written that "For ServiceClient, you need Azure IoT Hub
>   connection string, not device connection string"?

Device connection string: Connection string based on primary key used in API calls which allows device to communicate with Iot Hub. It allows you to **receive** C2D messages, not **send** C2D messages. IoT Hub [exposes its functionality to various actors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-endpoints#list-of-built-in-iot-hub-endpoints), like per-device and service.

> What is the performance's impact and resources' utilization, if we
>   hold a reference of the created ServiceClient object (or the Registry
>   Manager)?

You can check [IoT Hub throttling and you](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling) and [IoT Hub quotas and throttling](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/iot-hub-throttling-and-you/) for more detail.

Comment: For C2D messages is understandable. What is the difference between ServiceClient and  RegistryManager  according to server-side changes? (identity registry,  desired properties)  Why both classes do the same work, server-side?

Comment: Can we use ServiceClient as singleton or we should create instances every time? (like the HttpClient in .Net Core - singleton instead instances)

Comment: @stefan2410 [SerivceClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.serviceclient?view=azure-dotnet) Contains methods that services can use to send messages to devices. While for identity registry and desired properties, you need use [RegistryManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.registrymanager?view=azure-dotnet).

Comment: Rita Han, thanks.  Do you know about the use of ServiceClient as singleton?    Also, can you give me,a link of sample in GitHub   to listen for twin notifications (twinChanged events), if it exists?

Comment: @stefan2410 You don't need to create the ServiceClient instance every time.

Comment: @stefan2410 You can create a route, set the Data Source equal to twinChangeEvents and set endpoint to, for example, "events", then you can receive these twin changed events like [receiving the D2C messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-read-builtin).